# FB.getLoginStatus for local html file

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm creating a sample html file for testing fb login.  I used the code from the facebook developer page as follows but cannot get FB.getLoginStatus to be called.  For my facebook app settings i have sandbox mode NO and put a random site url:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MYAPPID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(stsResp) {
        alert('get login status callback!');
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` is a “protocol-relative” URL – it lets the browser decide whether to use HTTP or HTTPS when requesting the resource. But of course this doesn’t work when you’re testing from your file system, without a local web server. Put `http:` in front of it to get the JS SDK to load.

Comment: thanks for the explanation to get the sdk to load.  now it loads, but it my alert still doesn't show.  i also tried to put console.log to write to firebug. but no luck

Comment: I’m not sure if this works in a non-HTTP setting. You should set up a local web server for testing, it makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook JavaScript SDK does not support being used in a non-http/https context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) so you can map your localhost to a public HTTPS URL like this:

```
lt --subdomain yourapp --port 3001
```

And then you just setup https://yourapp.localtunnel.me as your website.